# Curator is not cleaning expired indices which come from CloudWatch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, amazon-cloudwatch, elk, elasticsearch-curator

I've setup an ELk stack using logstash (on EC2) and ElasticSearch Service from AWS. The source of the logs is coming from CloudWatch. I'm using Curator 5.8.1 to clean old indices.

The config:

```
---
client:
  hosts:
    - vpc-elasticsearch-xxx.eu-xxx-x.es.amazonaws.com
  port: 443
  use_ssl: True
  ssl_no_validate: False
  timeout: 300

logging:
  loglevel: DEBUG
```

The action.yml:

```
---
actions:
  1:
    action: delete_indices
    description: "Delete cloudwatch logs older than 7 days"
    options:
      timeout_override: 300
      continue_if_exception: False
      ignore_empty_list: True
      allow_ilm_indices: True
    filters:
      - filtertype: kibana
        exclude: True
      - filtertype: pattern
        kind: regex
        value: '^(cw-*).*$'
        exclude: True
      - filtertype: age
        source: creation_date
        direction: older
        unit: days
        unit_count: 7
```

The indices from CloudWatch appear in my stack like:

```
yellow open   cw-xxx-log-2020.07.13         B4NAbdsjQxuVLw0rxxxxx   5   1     751950            0      1.3gb          1.3gb
yellow open   cw-xx-xx-log-2020.07.16         YecRAK3hRGGYgwxQxxxx   5   1     584031            0        1gb            1gb
```

With the current configuration I want to remove them after 1 week. But as you can see. The indices above are still available in my cluster while they are older then 2 weeks.

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Your action configuration is wrong, you have `exclude: True` for the `filtertype` pattern, this will make every index that match the pattern to be [excluded from the actionable list](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/current/fe_exclude.html), which is the list of target index where the action, in this case the delete action, will be applied.

Try the following config based in the [elastic example](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/current/ex_delete_indices.html)

```
# remove index that start with cw-
actions:
  1:
    action: delete_indices
    description: >-
      Remove Index that start with cw
    options:
      ignore_empty_list: True
      disable_action: False
    filters:
    - filtertype: pattern
      kind: prefix
      value: cw-
    - filtertype: age
      source: creation_date
      direction: older
      unit: days
      unit_count: 7
```